# Golang "Best practice" to handle connection to database

Tags: go, mgo

I have a webservice written in Go and currently I have this Global package I import everywhere which contains the connection to MongoDB (via MGO), but I have to say that this feels very icky to me. What is the best practice of maintaining connections to datasources in Go? I come from a PHP world, hence the Global :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with importing a package which exports an initialized `*mgo.Session` object either as a package-level variable or through an accessor/initializer. Maybe the latter appeals better to classical "OOP-ists".

Comment: a Session is not a Conn. It abstracts a connection pool. Also, the Session accessor usually returns an error as well.